# An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file during Bulk insert from text file

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I was looking for the answer and could not fine the one for my question. It seems that I'm doing everything as explained, but it does not work in my case...

I'm doing a `bulk insert` with "|" as a field separator and I have a text file with a content like that:

```
111       |234567|111111111111|22222222222|33333333333333|444444444444|D|        |         |        |
222       |890111|222211111111|33332222222|34444333333333|555544444444|V|        |         |        |
```

At the end of each line when I look at `Notepad++` I have `"CRLF"`

I have a table named `Bulk_Table_Sample` with the same amount of columns as separated in the file

```
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Column7,Column8,Column9,Column10,Column11
```

And I have a view based on that table:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_Bulk_Table_Sample]
AS
    SELECT Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Column7,Column8,Column9,Column10,Column11
    FROM Bulk_Table_Sample
```

This is my Bulk Statement:

```
declare @cmd varchar(1000)
declare @FullFilePath varchar(1000)

set @FullFilePath = '\\File_Path\Data_Sample.DAT'

           SET @cmd = 'BULK INSERT dbo.vw_Bulk_Table_Sample FROM '''+ @FullFilePath +
                    ''' WITH(BATCHSIZE=20000,TABLOCK,FIRSTROW=1,FIELDTERMINATOR=''"|"'',ROWTERMINATOR=''\r'')' 
           EXEC (@cmd)
```

When executing the statement, I'm getting the following error:

```
Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 183
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 183
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 183
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

What is wrong with what I'm doing?

Comment: Look like something with the Dat file. you can cut the DAT file in the smaller DAT and try it, About 5 to 10 line, if that works then look for odd characters in the Dat file.

Comment: It is small file. It has only 2 lines

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146915/cannot-fetch-a-row-from-ole-db-provider-bulk-for-linked-server-null

Comment: I have a text file and in all the same bulk inserts we used '\n'

Comment: Your file sample doesn't include double quote characters (`"`) around the pipes (`|`), so shouldn't `FIELDTERMINATOR=''"|"''` be `FIELDTERMINATOR=''|''`?

Comment: Yes, I figured it out too. thx